# How do accept multiple authentication options in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, openid, cas

I want to protect a path in my VirtualHost but allow users a variety of authentication options (e.g. `mod-auth-cas`, `mod-auth-openid` and `mod-auth-digest`.)  How do I set up the virtual host definition to allow multiple `auth-type`s for the same location?

Comment: What version of Apache httpd?

Comment: Let's say Apache 2.2

Answer (score 6):

The problem with multiple authentication types is they tend to have irreconcilable protocols.  You can try the technique shown in the [Shibboleth documentation](http://shib.kuleuven.be/secureKUL/), where you put everything in a subdirectory, create a symlink to that directory for each authentication type you want to support, then configure each symlink location for a different authentication type.

```
<Location /basic>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</Location>
<Location /cas>
    AuthType CAS
    require valid-user
</Location>
<Location /openid>
    AuthOpenIDEnabled On
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 5):

i had the almost same situation, solved like the following:

at server config level, in the apache2.conf (assuming Debian based distros)

```
<AuthnProviderAlias method1 auth1_name  >
# config options
# ...
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias method2 auth2_name  >
# config options
# ...
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

in the Virtual Host specific conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
# config options
# ...

<Location /your_location>
# config options
AuthBasicProvider auth1_name auth2_name
# other needed config options
# ...
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

in this way you can use different authorization/authentication methods with different names in the same Location directive for differnt VirtualHosts

more details of my solution in a short blog post: [link text](http://moonwatcher.it/shortposts/apache-multiple-authentication-methods-and-options.html)

HTH, ciao :)
Gianluca

Comment: This is a really great technique. However, it doesn't solve the poster's question of using different AuthTypes

Comment: Thank you Kamil :) i didn't read the later OP comments, in the first post is mentioned 'location', from Apache docs i read that the AuthType context is 'directory'. So, sorry for the OffTopic.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried "[Satisfy Any](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy)" ?

Comment: Can I have multiple AuthTypes in the same Location block? as in "AuthType CAS; AuthType Basic; AuthType OpenID; Satisfy Any"?

Comment: Only the last AuthType will hold sway.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to differentiate authentication based on the content of the HTTP header with  clause:

```
 <If "%{HTTP:Authorization} =~ /^Basic/">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
 </If>
 <Elseif "%{HTTP:Authorization} =~ /^Bearer/">
   AuthOpenIDEnabled On
   Require valid-user
 </Elseif>
 <Else>
   AuthType CAS
   Require valid-user
 </Else>
```